# Embedded form not working in Episerver content block

Tags: jquery, forms, episerver

*This question has been edited as I learn more about my issue.*

I am tasked with embedding a MailChimp subscription form into a content block in our Episerver installation.

The form doesn't work. It looks great! But when the user clicks "Submit", it simply refreshes the page.

- The forms work when hosted at Mailchimp but not when embedded into a content block on our Episerver site (have tried them all).
- The forms work when embedded in a static, non-hosted HTML file on my desktop.
- I have disabled every jquery script on the master test page, wondering if something there (a validator, perhaps) was interfering with the form. But after disabling all the scripts, the form still refreshes the page when submitted.

I have no idea what could be causing whatever conflict it is that would make a simple HTML form ignore its "action=" attribute and rather refresh the page. It's of course an error or piece of ignorance on my part: but in my digging I haven't been able to find the answer, so I'm asking you all for help.

If I haven't included enough information, please let me know what else to include.

**linked scripts at the top of the root master page file**

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
```

**scripts at the bottom of the root master page file**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": false };</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=redacted"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (document.location.hostname == "redacted") {

                (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
                    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
                })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

                ga('create', 'redacted', 'auto');
                ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
                ga('send', 'pageview');

            }
        </script>
```

**script from another included ascx file (mainnav)**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Setup drop down menu
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

        // Fix input element click problem
        $('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**the form, in an ascx view file**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MailChimpBlockControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="JamesTrustWF.Web.Views.Blocks.MailChimpBlockControl" %>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" style="margin: 0;padding:0;">

        <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action="url-provided-by-mailchimp" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <h2>Subscribe</h2>
        <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-FNAME">First Names  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
        </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="redacted" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <!--End mc_embed_signup-->

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just embedded HTML there's nothing Epi specific you need to worry about.  I would start by getting the form working on a page rather than on a block.  If you copy the code in your HTML file into the Epi view, does it work?

This is using web-forms so you could try adding the `runat="server"` onto the form or the button

Also, I'm assuming you have a valid URL for url-provided-by-mailchimp.  Ig you look in your console do you see any error?

Comment: Thanks so much, Jon!
- I've seen `runat="server"` quite a bit in the code. Will try that straightaway, for both the form and the button.
- I didn't realise there is a potential difference between behaviour on a page versus on a block. Please forgive my ignorance: what is "Epi view"? I'm happy to copy my code there and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Jon, when I added `runat="server"` to the form element, the page completely didn't render. The error, I think, was "Unable to [find/render/locate/display?] link,"

When I added `runat="server"` to the button tag, everything loaded, but the behaviour didn't change. Submitting the form simply refreshes the page.

Comment: I've also tried adding `runat="server"` to the `<div>` elements which contain the form, and no change in the inexplicable behaviour. I did some Google searching on Epi view, and I still have no idea what that is.

Comment: Found the issue. Good grief.

For some reason, whoever built this site has enclosed the ENTIRE page in a `<form>` element, all the way up in the root master page. I have no idea why this was necessary; I'll contact the guy. In the meantime, I'm not sure if I'll hide a hidden form in the root master page, update its fields via javascript, and submit it via javascript, using this form as a dummy (and not as an actual `<form>` element), or if I'll come up with something completely different.

Comment: Hahaha...  sounds like an interesting architectural choice.  Could you pass a page property to disable the parent form on that particular page, e.g. if statement it based on a falg

Comment: I could maybe do that, but I'm afraid to do it before learning _why_ the original builder chose to make the entire thing a form in the first place. What if I break some built-in functionality I'm as yet unaware of? Unfortunately the knowledge transfer on this was really not adequate, and there's no documentation. :-(
So I'm left with reading through all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add novalidate attribute to your form, this might be caused by a validation issue.

Comment: Thanks; the novalidate attribute is already part of the form. :-(

Comment: Oh sorry I didn’t saw that, did you check if you are making a call to mailchimp? Just enable preserve log if you are not already, otherwise the call won’t show

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I'm sure I haven't enabled a preserve log, because I don't know what that is. I'll search around and try to find out what that is and how to do it.

Comment: Hi again Ivan, I enabled preserve log in Chrome developer tools (that's nifty--I was wondering how to check where my form was trying to go). It appears that the form sent the data to the exact same page it's embedded in, and not to `https://redacted.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=redacted&amp;id=redacted` as the `action=` attribute of the form element specifies. My big question is WHY? What's overriding the action attribute of my form?

Comment: Found the issue. Good grief.

For some reason, whoever built this site has enclosed the ENTIRE page in a `<form>` element, all the way up in the root master page. I have no idea why this was necessary; I'll contact the guy. In the meantime, I'm not sure if I'll hide a hidden form in the root master page, update its fields via javascript, and submit it via javascript, using this form as a dummy (and not as an actual `<form>` element), or if I'll come up with something completely different.